# Where do non-standard shutter speeds come from?

Tags: shutter-speed

When I google "shutter speed" and explore a few first hits, there is always listed only the standard shutter speeds - 1/1000,  1/500,  1/250,  1/125,  1/60,  1/30,  1/15 etc

But, when I go looking at photos in Flickr, I sometimes see photos taken with shutter speeds like 1/320 or 1/80 and similar oddities.

Where do these odd speeds come from?

I know we are talking about electronic devices here, so naturally we are not tied to the old mechanical camera limitations. So, can a shutter speed 1/320 be manually chosen in a modern digicamera, or is it a product of camera set to Auto-mode?

Comment: Among all the answers is a tiny detail that may make this easier to understand. There is a difference between the setting indication and the actual shutter speed. You can set the shutter speed to indicate your desire; but, in actuality, the shutter speed will not occur as indicated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those listed are full stops.  Most cameras allow you to increment shutter speed and aperture in half-stops or one-third stops, and you can select intermediate values manually.

- If you have the camera set to half-stops, then you'll have 1/350 between 1/250 and 1/500.
- If you have 1/3 stop increments set, you'll have 1/320 and 1/400

To work these out, a full stop is double the light.  A half stop then is the square root of 2 times, or 1.4 (so that if you go up a half stop, then another half stop, you multiply the 1.4 factor together, and 1.4 * 1.4 = 2, which is your full stop)

- So 250 times 1.4 = 350
- and 350 * 1.4 = 500

For 1/3 stops, it's the cube root of 2, or 1.26x

- 250 * 1.26 = 315 (rounded to 320)
- 315 * 1.26 = 396 (rounded to 400)
- 396 * 1.26 = 500

Note that numbers are rounded, considerably in some cases, for convenience.  The actual shutter speeds the camera produces are probably more precise values than these.

1/2       1/3
Stops    Stops

<kbd>1000</kbd><kbd>1000</kbd>
<kbd>750</kbd> <kbd>800</kbd> 
<kbd>500</kbd> <kbd>640</kbd> 
<kbd>350</kbd> <kbd>500</kbd> 
<kbd>250</kbd> <kbd>400</kbd> 
<kbd>180</kbd> <kbd>320</kbd> 
<kbd>125</kbd> <kbd>250</kbd> 
<kbd>90</kbd>  <kbd>200</kbd> 
<kbd>60</kbd>  <kbd>160</kbd> 
<kbd>45</kbd>  <kbd>125</kbd> 
<kbd>30</kbd>  <kbd>100</kbd> 
<kbd>23</kbd>  <kbd>80</kbd>  
<kbd>15</kbd>  <kbd>60</kbd>  
<kbd>11</kbd>  <kbd>50</kbd>  
<kbd>8</kbd>   <kbd>40</kbd>  
<kbd>6</kbd>   <kbd>30</kbd>  
<kbd>4</kbd>   <kbd>25</kbd>  
<kbd>3</kbd>   <kbd>20</kbd>  
<kbd>2</kbd>   <kbd>15</kbd>  
<kbd>1.5</kbd> <kbd>13</kbd>  
<kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>10</kbd>  
    <kbd>8</kbd>   
    <kbd>6</kbd>   
    <kbd>5</kbd>   
    <kbd>4</kbd>   
    <kbd>3</kbd>   
    <kbd>2.5</kbd> 
    <kbd>2</kbd>   
    <kbd>1.6</kbd> 
    <kbd>1.3</kbd> 
    <kbd>1</kbd>

Comment: And yes, some cameras have **stepless shutter speeds** in P, A/Av, full auto and scene modes.

Comment: @Ryccardo Which cameras?

Comment: I personally know the Nikon W35 and the Electro Yashica 35 do :) Even many digital cameras do -- however you'll only see that in the EXIF. See photo.net/nikon-camera-forum/00LgqA

Comment: 1/250 sec is really 1/256 sec. Every thing is based on powers of 2 starting with 1 second (2^0). The 1/2 stops steps above 1/250 (256) are 362.04 and 512. The 1/3 stop steps are 322.54, 406.37, and 512.

Comment: Many 1970s aperture-priority SLRs actually are stepless - the exposure automation circuitry is *analog* and would have been *more* complex if one wanted it to work in discrete steps. Example: Minolta XE series, counterexample: Canon A1 (this one is actually microcomputer controlled).

Answer (score 3):

The list you quoted are full stops. Most cameras will also allow you to select 1/2 or 1/3 stops, which are spaced in between the full stops. Just as with f/numbers, they are often rounded to make them easier to remember and refer to. Since they are mathematically based on √2 and ³√2 they don't always compute to nice, even numbers.

Depending on what application you are viewing your photo with, sometimes both the *shutter speed (Tv) and aperture (Av) setting* and the *actual Tv and Av* will be displayed in the EXIF information. For example, I just looked at a photo using Irfanview that was manually exposed at 1/80 sec. @ f/3.5. In the EXIF information Exposure Time was displayed as 1/80 seconds and FNumber was displayed as 3.50. Further down in the EXIF info Shutter Speed Value was displayed as 1/83 seconds and Aperture Value was listed as F 3.51. These numbers are not the theoretical mathematical values expected, but rather the value that my camera/lens actually uses when a picture is exposed using those settings.