# Can I trigger a Godox SK400 with Yongnuo triggers?

Tags: yongnuo, wireless-triggers, godox

Can anyone tell me ... can I trigger a Godox SK400 strobe with a Yongnuo trigger/ transmitter? I use a Yongnuo speedlight and transmitter but I am about to buy a Godox SK400 strobe and would like make sure that I can use the transmitter / trigger with both.

Answer (score 5):

The only way you could trigger the [Godox SK400](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WS10N7E) with your current setup would be to use it in "dumb" slave mode where the flash from the Yongnuo speedlight would trigger it.

The radio in your Yongnuo trigger (regardless of which Yongnuo system you have - there are at least three separate Yongnuo radio protocols that are not compatible with each other: YN622, RF603/RF605/YN560, and RT) will neither control nor trigger a Godox SK400 without additional equipment. For control as well as triggering you need either the [Godox FT-16 transmitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DMSACEQ) and the FT-16 receiver module that plugs into the remote port on the SK400 *or* a [Godox X1T](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C6XHH6S) transmitter (linked is the Nikon version, but it is also available in Canon and Sony versions) and an [XTR-16](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01ANFQ22G) receiver plugged into the SK400.

You could use an additional Yongnuo receiver (that uses the same protocol as your current Yongnuo transmitter) with a wired sync output to fire the SK400 via the 3.5mm sync port. Of course you would also need to purchase a cable that fits your Yongnuo receiver on one end and the 3.5mm port on the SK400 on the other end, and you'd only be able to tell the flash to *fire* via wireless radio. All settings would still require physically making them on the SK400's controls. But I doubt *fire only* is what you are looking for. If *fire only* is sufficient then the use of an additional receiver plus sync cord gains you very little compared to just triggering via optical slave mode.

Comment: @inkista "... *only way*... *with your current setup*..." (i.e w/out buying anything else). I think it is also reasonable to presume the question implies wireless *control* as well as *fire* command.

Comment: The multiple incompatible Yongnuo radio protocols caught me by surprise too. I "upgraded" to a newer Yongnuo flash only to find it incompatible with my other gear. I'm considering switching to Godox now because they seem to have one system that can do both speedlights and studio strobes.

Comment: They're not totally incompatible. The YN-560/RF603/RF605 protocol can manually control power, zoom, and triggering of YN622 receivers made since the end of 2014. But yeah, the Godox system is more or less seamless across manual only speedlights, TTL speedlights, and radio controlled studio lights.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can use Yongnuo (or nearly any RF-based) triggers to fire the Godox SK400, since it has a 1/8" (3.5mm) miniplug sync port.  You simply have to cable an additional Yongnuo receiver in the triggering system you're using (e.g., YN-622 or RF-605) to the strobe's sync port (this may require a 2.5mm→3.5mm adapter), and the Yongnuo transmitter on your camera's hotshoe will fire the strobe remotely.

Bear in mind, however, that this will be "manual-only" triggering. All you can tell the strobe to do is fire in sync. Nothing else. Depending on the duration of the pulse, you may be able to use the [tailsync](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61635) capabilities of the YN-622 to go past your max. sync speed, but I wouldn't count on it.

If you want to have remote control from the camera of the power over both the flash and the SK400 strobe, however, you'd probably be better off to dump the Yongnuo gear, and move to [the Godox X 2.4 GHz radio system](https://www.hypop.com.au/blogs/blogs/a-comprehensive-master-guide-to-godox-lights-and-accessories) (rebranded as Flashpoint R2 by Adorama). This lets you mix both manual and TTL speedlights, bare bulb flashes, and studio strobes, with remote power control, HSS, and (if the flash performs it) TTL.

The XTR16 receiver can be plugged into the USB-A port on the SK400, for remote radio control from an Godox X transmitter (e.g., X1T, Xpro). But power control might be wonky, given that the SK400 does not do ratio power control, and some of the Godox X transmitters do not do the decimal power control the older Godox studio strobes use. It would be better to exchange your SK400 for [current Mk II, Mk III, or MS series model](https://www.godox.com/studio-flash/), which have Godox X receivers built-in and ratio power control, so they're fully compatible with the Godox X transmitters.

Comment: @MichaelClark, so, you're downvoting because of something the OP _didn't actually state_, but you inferred? And it's not like the strobe comes with the FT-16 triggers, either. If my answer is soooo wrong, why did you edit yours to match? (why I removed my comment and downvote, btw).

Comment: The additional paragraph at the end of my answer is mostly needed to explain the last line of that paragraph. I added the reference to the X1T and XTR-16 to provide links to those products as they are currently referenced by amazon. Although Flash Havoc calls them XT-16 in the article you linked, the receivers seem to only be listed by sellers as XTR-16 and XTR-16s units.

Comment: I'll look at your answer again and reconsider the downvote. But I do think it should probably either make clear that adding a YN receiver to use the sync port on the SK400 is little different than using dumb "slave" mode *or* explain what advantages there are to be gained by using the YN receiver and patch cord to the sync plug.

Comment: Thanks Michael Clark & Inkista ... I'm a bit technically challenged so lots of useful info here... thanks.

Yes Inkista breaking away from Youngnuo will have to happen at some point soon but for now it's what I'm stuck with. I used a friend's Godox setup recently and it was user friendly and very effective.  

So Michael you are right I have decided best option for now is to trigger the SK400 optically using the Yongnuo speedlight.
Thanks for your responses I really appreciate it.

Comment: @MichaelClark Thanks for the XTR-16 correction. The s unit, though, is for the Vings (different connector), doesn't apply in this instance.

Comment: You're welcome. That is why there is no link in my answer for the XTR-16s and why I felt the XTR-16 needed to be specifically identified.