# Are there any electric flashes that will work at shutter speeds like ¹⁄₁₀₀₀th of a second?

Tags: flash, shutter-speed, sync-speed

Most flashes fire at about 1/1000 sec, and can usually not be properly fired faster than the red number on the speed dial (my case being 1/60). Using the flash higher than that red number will result in badly exposed photos.

[image]

Some cameras go to 1/125, I've seen some max out at around 1/240 or 1/250. However is there a flash that I can use with up to 1/1000? Flash bulbs would emit long enough that they could be used at about any shutter speed, but I hear those have a one time use and I would not be looking forward to find vintage bulbs or spend money every time I use flash.

Is there an electronic flash that I can connect to my camera's FP sync port and be able to use at around any shutter speed?

Comment: Related: [What exactly is flash sync speed, and should it be a factor in a buying decision?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/836/what-exactly-is-flash-sync-speed-and-should-it-be-a-factor-in-a-buying-decision)

Comment: Related: [Is there no crossover point where shutter speed overtakes flash duration?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61635)

Comment: This is a fine question, but you may get more helpful results if you describe _the lighting problem you are trying to solve_ (perhaps in a new, separate question).

Comment: Hey, that's my Minolta 201!  :-)

Comment: Try looking up Phase One cameras :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That camera with 1/60 sync (and says ASA) must be at least 40 years old.  :)   More modern cameras commonly allow 1/200 second shutter with flash.

But this limitation (of not allowing flash with 1/1000 second shutter) is due to the type of shutter in the camera. It is not a property of the flash, electronic or bulb. It is a property of the camera shutter.

Focal plane shutters back in the 1960s were 1/60 second sync, but the focal plane shutters have gotten faster now, 1/200 second sync is common.

There is (or was) a FP sync flash bulb, called FP sync (for Focal Plane), which is a longer burning bulb, which allows any faster shutter speed.  The issue is that when faster than sync speed, the focal plane shutter becomes a narrow slit moving across the film.  At speeds less than sync speed, the shutter is fully open, which allows flash, even very fast flash. But at faster shutter speeds, it is just a narrow moving slit which is all that gets illuminated by the fast flash. Shutter speed is too fast to sync with flash.

The longer burning flashbulb allows any narrow slit to move, to occur at any point of the slit travel (the longer burning bulb will still be burning there).  The faster shutter speed slit does of course seriously reduce the light, you have to open aperture to compensate for the lost exposure time.

In electronic flashes, there is a flash mode called High Speed Sync (HSS), which mimics the longer burning FP sync bulbs, to allow any fast shutter speed. The HSS flash "burns continuously" for the entire shutter slit travel time.  It is NOT fast flash, the opposite, continuous like daylight, it cannot stop any motion. But it is High Speed Sync, meaning it does allow any fast shutter speed.  Both the camera and the flash have to support HSS, and must be compatible with each other too.

Comment: You explained it well,  I am aware about how slower and faster shutter speeds affect the image, but because flash bulbs burn for a long time, they can be used at about any shutter speed (after adjusting aperture to compensate for light gain or loss of course). Is there any electronic reusable flash unit that can fire as long as the flash bulbs? My camera is actually from the 60s and it does have an FP sync port, along with an X contact, so if a modern FP flash existed, I would be able to use it with my camera.

Comment: The only solution I can imagine for your camera is that a quick search found http://www.colescameras.com/flashbulbs.htm which claims to offer #6 and #25 and #26 in FP flash bulbs. As said, there are HSS electronic flashes, but they must communicate with the camera, which means a modern compatible camera.  PocketWizard has a HyperSync mode which aids cameras to use the longer duration of a slow burning (bigger) electronic flash to somewhat mimic HSS (without being HSS).

Answer (score 5):

> Is there an electronic flash that I can connect to my camera's FP sync port and be able to use at around any shutter speed?

The problem isn't the flash, it's the shutter. At exposure durations shorter than the flash sync speed, the two curtains of a typical shutter are always covering some part of the sensor film, so there's no point when the flash can fire and expose the entire sensor.

One option is to get a camera with a different type of shutter. Some cameras, like the Fuji X-series cameras, have a leaf shutter that by its nature exposes the entire sensor. This allows very high sync speeds -- the Fuji X100 have a sync speed of 1/4000s.

A more common option is High Speed Sync, in which a speedlight is pulsed many times over the course of the exposure, providing illumination for a much longer period than a typical single flash, so that it gives an even exposure. Since HSS doesn't need to expose the whole sensor at the same time, you can use it at much higher speeds.

Considering the age of your camera, it's unlikely that HSS is an option for the camera you have. Your best bet would probably be to provide enough continuous light instead of using flash.

Comment: An FP flash is basically continuous light but it's brighter than, say, using an LED light. The bulbs burn long enough that they can be used with any shutter speed, with an adjustment of aperture of course. Using a LED would be ineffective, as they just aren't bright enough. I do not "need" a flash bulb, what I need exactly is a flash that is as bright as a xenon bulb but lasts longer than the typical 1/1000 of normal flashes. Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Camera speedlights for example, are constant voltage, but shorten their firing duration to vary power level. Lower power level is much shorter than 1/1000 second. But at full maximum power, about any will be longer than 1/1000, more likely around 1/250 or 1/300 second T1.  ***However***, regardless of normal flash duration (excepting the longer special HSS mode), the focal plane shutter still cannot sync any flash at speeds faster than its sync speed, 1/60 second in old days, commonly 1/200 second today.  This makes your question very hard to answer differently.

Comment: I think you may actually be asking if any flash duration is as long as your 1/60 sync speed travel time (which is approx 1/60 second too), and I think that answer is no.  I would ask why you need it? Speedlights are called speedlights  because the fast flash will stop incredible motion, using any slow shutter speed (like 1/60, or even 1 second), assuming that the ambient is not bright enough to show any continuous light blur at that setting. The fast flash will not show it.

Comment: @ToastHouse, you seem to be fixated on needing a flash, but Caleb's answer as I read it is pointing out that you're asking the wrong question. The right question is: how can I get the illumination that I need for my shot? Flash isn't the only way of providing light.

Comment: @Peter Taylor In that case, how can I get the illumination that I need for my shot? I am aware that there are other ways to to provide light, however I need it to be bright and last long enough that I won't get any black lines in the image. If it is a bright day and I take an image at 1/1000, the sun acts as a constant light source that I can use at high shutter speeds. At night, and indoors, I can only use 1/60 with my flash. Technically, light is light, and if I had a long lasting flash, my camera would still pick it up the same way it would pick up sunlight outdoors.

Comment: @ToastHouse It sounds like you're trying to use flash as though it were a constant source. That's what HSS or Auto FP modes do, but as I said above, you probably don't have that option with the camera you're using. If your goal is to shoot *faster* than 1/60 because you want to freeze motion, then use the flash to your advantage: eliminate as much ambient light as possible and shoot with flash at the camera's normal sync speed of 1/60s. The very short duration of the powerful flash will freeze motion even though the shutter happens to be open longer.

Comment: @Peter Taylor Yes, I am trying to use flash longer, not as an entirely constant source, but long enough that I can use other shutter speeds besides 1/60 (A 1/200 flash instead of 1/1000)

Comment: @ToastHouse When you take a photo at 1/250s, any given point on the film is exposed for that long, but it still takes 1/60s for the shutter to travel across the film plane. If you had a flash with a duration of 1/200s and you shot with a shutter speed of 1/250s, you'd end up with only about 1/3 of the shot being exposed. At the sync speed or slower, though, the shutter opens to reveal the entire frame at once, so a very short flash pulse is able to expose the whole frame.

Comment: @toastHouse  >>At night, and indoors, I can only use 1/60 with my flash.  But what you are missing is that a camera speedlight flash is much faster than any possible shutter speed. Speedlght flash is how high speed photography is done, even with a 1/60 second shutter. In fairly dim ambient light, the picture is black without the flash. But the flash illuminates it and is very bright and very fast. See http://www.scantips.com/speed.html for the idea. The samples all used a 1.5 second shutter, but the flash is up to 1/30,000 second speed. Any manual $60 Chinese speedlight will do this.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, but whyou would my camera have an FP Sync port if it would act similar to an X contact (other than the fact that the bulb warms up)? I hear on various sites that because FP bulbs last about 1/200 they can be used with about any shutter speed.

Comment: @ToastHouse [FP flash bulbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_synchronization) did what you say -- they had a longer burn time so that the light lasted for the duration of the shutter's traversal. This is exactly what the AutoFP/HSS mode offered in some speedlights does, but as stated it's unlikely that your camera will work with those.

Comment: FP and X are different timing, because like other flash bulbs, it takes several milliseconds for the bulb to ignite and become bright. FP waits for that to occur before opening the shutter (like other flash bulbs).  Electronic flash X is immediate, no waiting. Actually, for the "continuous" light of FP or HSS, you want the light to be on before the shutter opens, until just after it closes. So HSS has to be matched to the camera model.

Comment: You're asking the question wrong, which is causing the confusion.  You should read up a little on "stopping motion flash photography",  http://www.google.com/search?q=stopping+motion+flash+photography             We can't use High Speed as keywords, because that pulls up HSS, which is the slowest possible choice. HSS or FP can allow 1/1000 second shutter, but the solution using speedlghts is much faster than any shutter. Brighter too.