# Why can't I get high-speed sync with my Nikon D750 and Yongnuo YN560 IV?

Tags: nikon, flash, yongnuo, high-speed-sync

I have looking at reasons for why my Yongnuo YN560IV would not fire at Highspeed sync on my Nikon D750. I tried some setups, but whenever I go further up than 1/250s shutter speed, the flash won't do the high-speed sync. It will not burst the flash at all, only a single flash.

Any idea why?

Comment: HSS still looks like a single flash... are you getting dark bands in the images?

Comment: Possible duplicate question:  https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/93805/39427

Comment: Hi Steven, Yes, after 1/250s it only flashes 1 time, then I get dark bands, Do i need the YN560TX to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your YN-560IV over and look at its foot. The reason why you can't do HSS with it is that it's a single-pin speedlight, and can therefore only receive the sync (fire) signal on that pin.  It doesn't have the other pins to receive TTL or HSS/FP commands from the camera.  You need a speedlight that can perform HSS and that has all four of the pins Nikon uses for signalling, like a Godox TT685N, Yongnuo YN-968N, or Nikon SB-700, if you plan on using it on the hotshoe of the camera or on the hotshoe of a trigger.

The internal radio transceiver in the YN-560IV only allows for zoom and manual power adjustments. It does not allow for HSS, like the transceiver in a Godox TT600 does. So getting a YN-560-TX won't help, either.

See also:

- [Any way to force HSS for Yongnuo 560 IV](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93770/any-way-to-force-hss-for-yongnuo-560-iv/)
- [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

For a camera to work with Nikon HSS, its specs must say HSS and must say "for Nikon".  So the reason is that the Yongnuo YN560 IV spec does not mention either, so forget HSS that way.  That model is a manual flash.

A model like the Yongnuo YN-568 III (the one "for Nikon") does have HSS in its specs, and would be expected to work.  Then the camera can communicate with it and can setup HSS mode if selected (with a camera model like the D750 that also supports HSS).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It is indeed not possible. It does not have what I want. I will return it and buy another that has HSS. Thank you.