# Cannot set up external Yongnuo flashes with Canon 5D Mark II

Tags: camera-settings, yongnuo, canon-5d-mark-ii, high-speed-sync

I use my Canon 5D Mark II with multiple YN-560 Mark IV flashes, triggered by a YN560-TX external flash control.
I tried to set up the external flash control but I failed. It says `flash is not compatible`. Of course all flashes are powered on. I tried to shoot with high shutter speed (<= 1/1000s), but I can only shoot at 1/320 at the most.

What can I do to increase shutter speed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the flash you mentioned, but my guess is that the [sync speed](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/836/9161) is limited to 1/320.

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to increase shutter to decrease ambient light while using the flash in mixed lighting situations. Given that you're maxed - if the flash has more power you can squeeze out of it, you could try an ND filter instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What configuration would limit my DSLR's shutter speed to 1/200?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34303/what-configuration-would-limit-my-dslrs-shutter-speed-to-1-200)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem when connecting canon 600d with flash YN560 III](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/92984/problem-when-connecting-canon-600d-with-flash-yn560-iii)

Answer (score 3):

The YN-560 series are manual only flashes, so they [don't support](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/59173/15871) things like TTL or High Speed Sync, which is what you need to shoot above the camera's sync speed. The 5D Mark II's [flash sync speed](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34303/15871) is 1/200s.

For Yongnuo products, you are looking at the YN-568EX II or the YN685, which has a built in radio receiver. You will need a YN-622C or YN622C-TX to trigger these. That system supports the more advanced features that you are looking for.

Comment: @vanbinh - how about accepting the answer?